# Java - tell if a String is interned?

Tags: java, string

So the question here is pretty simple: is there a way to tell if a `String` in Java is interned? My guess is no, but I'm wondering if anyone knows better.

Comment: I wonder *why* do you need this information? If it's for optimization to avoid unnecessary call to intern I'd say don't do it and just intern away..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only way you can find out if a `String` is interned is to call `intern()` and check if it returns itself:

```
boolean hasBeenInternedBefore = myString.intern() == myString;
```

This obviously has the drawback of interning the `String` when it wasn't interned before.

Going partially off-topic, there's a way to do "custom" interning with an explicit pool using the [`Interner` interface](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) of [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (using the implementations exposed by the [`Interners` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html)). This has the advantage of being able to let the `Interner` itself (and thuse the pool) being garbage collected when it's no longer referenced.

Comment: Didn't though about that way. It seems like an equivalent of destructive test in forensics.

Comment: @Riduidel At least you get to know if the cat *was* alive or not :-)

Comment: How about `hasBeenInternedBefore = myString == new String(myString).intern()`?

Comment: @aioobe Any time `intern` is called it interns the string -- the intern'ed value is then separate from the initial strings lifetime. Unless I'm missing something the withe explicit ctor.

Comment: @aioobe: I don't see the advantage in that. My version doesn't *change* `myString` either, it only places a copy of it into the intered `String` pool. In those effects your version is equivalent, but it always creates one more `String` object.

Comment: @Joachim, I don't see the advantage either. It was just a reply to your "The drawback of interning the String ..."

Comment: @pst - no, you can say, that the cat is dead *now*. The test may kill the cat before it really starts (just to stay in the picture)

Comment: It's just like 'go outside and check if you are there'. If you call intern(), your String will be internalized anyway so you could return true anyway with that solution.

Comment: @lechlukasz - not exactly, `myString.intern()` returns the reference of the interned String that is equal to `myString`. It does not change the stored reference in `myString`! So the result may be `false`.

Comment: loving the schrodinger's cat references.

Comment: @Andread_D yes, it does not change the stored reference, but the content of the string will be interned after that call!

Comment: @JoachimSauer: This test has unpleasant side effect: it will always intern `myString` thus blowing PermGen. So one can get OOM while using this "innocent" test.

Comment: @dma_k: yes, and I even mention that very fact in my third paragraph.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Thanks for the link to Guava's `Interners`. It's a pity that `Interner` interface does not have `boolean isInterned(E)` method, which would be very relevant to the question. Although it's not difficult to implement it by oneself...

Comment: @JoachimSauer hi i am new to java and i didn't understood the drawback(you mentioned in your answer) exactly. can you explain that in somewhat more clearly

Comment: @sunny: the string pool (i.e. "where interned strings are stored") has traditionally been pretty permanent and has not been garbage collected. This has changed (I believe sometime in the Java 6 timeframe), so that it's now garbage collected just like any other object. But people are still reluctant to use it (probably because there is no way to tell if you're using a "new" or an "old" implementation).

Comment: At least on Java 7, this returns false positives. `hasBeenInternedBefore` is `true` if the string's contents have never been interned before. `myString` is interned and returned as itself, so the equality holds. It only tests `contentsHaventBeenInternedBeforeAsAnotherStringObject`.

Comment: @DanGetz indeed, this kind of test is entirely worthless. It only tells you, whether there is an interned string with the same contents and different identity.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to check if the particular `String` object was already interned, but it inserts the contents into the string pool if those contents weren't already interned. Create a new `String` object with the same contents, intern that, and compare to your original object:

```
new String(s).intern() == s
```

This works because of the fact that `new String(s) != s`. Consider each possible situation:

1. `s` is interned in the string pool. `new String(s)` has the same contents as `s`, so `intern()` called on it will return `s`. The expression's result is `true`.
2. `s` is not interned in the string pool, but another equal `String` object is—let's call it `s2`. `intern()` will return `s2`, so the expression's result is `false`.
3. `s` is not interned in the string pool, and neither is any `String` equal to it. In this case, `new String(s)` will be interned into the string pool, which unfortunately modifies the string pool. Because this is not the same `String` object as `s`, the expression's result is `false`.

Thus the above expression will correctly test if `s` is interned in the string pool or not. The following test demonstrates this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String interned = new String(new char[] { 'i', 'n', 't' }).intern();
    String notInterned = new String(new char[] { 'n', 'o', 't' });
    System.out.println("Case 1: " + wasInterned(interned));
    System.out.println("Case 2: " + wasInterned(new String(interned)));
    System.out.println("Case 3: " + wasInterned(notInterned));
}

public static boolean wasInterned(String s) {
    return new String(s).intern() == s;
}
```

When run, the output is:

```
 Case 1: true
 Case 2: false
 Case 3: false
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't *look* inside the repository of interned strings and can't get a set of all interned Strings.

Testing, if a given String has been interned already creates a nice dilemma (a common problem with measurements by the way): the measuring itself may affect the repository of interned Strings ;)

To test, if a repository contains a given String, we need to compare that String to (worst case) all Strings in that repository - with the risk, that JVM interns this reference String *before* we start comparing... which would return a `true` although the String wasn't interned before the test ;)

But apart from this, I don't see any practical use in knowing if the virtual machine has interned a String already or not. Interning is cheap enough, just intern it if needed. (And if there was a practical use, the `String` class would offer a native test method)

Comment: Interning is cheap, but if an application handles an enormous amount of Strings, the memory consumption could become a problem I guess.

Comment: AFAIK, there may be problems when too many strings get interned, probably because of them landing in the PermSpace. Consider using WeakInterner from Guava in such a case.

Comment: @maaartinus Even today, without the PermGen space, in the HotSpot JVM, the table of interned strings has a fixed size, a ridiculously small fixed size on older JVMs, which leads to lots of collisions, even when not using it exhaustively. Besides that, it implies modifying a globally visible data structure in a thread safe way, in other words, can never be a cheap operation at all.

Answer (score 0):

No. Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to check - just `intern` them to be sure or don't rely on interning.  If you need interned or non-interned strings for testing or experimenting, you can make them:

Interned:

```
s = someArbitraryString.intern();
```

Non-interned:

```
s = new String(someArbitraryString);
```