# How do you list the string that been internalized in a jvm?

Tags: java, permgen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - tell if a String is interned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883821/java-tell-if-a-string-is-interned)

I would like to have a list of the string that have been internalized by a jvm, either because they are literal are because the method [intern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) as been called on them.  How can I generate it?

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you need it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. the first question is about a string, the second one about obtaining a list.

Comment: I have a problem of out of memory in perm gen space, seeing which string are added could help me why the perm gen is growing so much at certain point.

Comment: I added another related question, since this one was not understood as I intended : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180006/which-debugging-tool-can-list-strings-internalized

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total size of all interned strings as:

```
$ jmap -permstat 543
Attaching to process ID 543, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 19.1-b02-334
14584 intern Strings occupying 1603648 bytes.
finding class loader instances ..Warning: skipping invalid TLAB for thread t@44819
...
```

Comment: The question is about the list, not the number.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I generate it?

You can't within a running program.  There is no API for iterating the intern'd string pool.

---

You could in theory do it via a debug agent.  It would involve:

1. Traversing the reachable objects to find ALL `String` instances.
2. For each one, testing if `str == str.intern()`.

However, this process is going to be expensive, and is going to pollute the string pool (the permgen heap) with lots of Strings that have been interned unnecessarily.  Besides, this only works when all application threads have been stopped by the debug agent, so an application can't use this approach to examine its own string pool.

Comment: This is theoretically doable on a small application, but it will fail with an out of memory in perm gen space with a huge application.  Even if I increase the perm gen space enough, the goal is to make comparison of the list at different point.    It won't be possible to do a valid comparison since the lecture modify the result.